# Unable to approve KNC token. Fails with error: "Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM"

Tags: web3js, tokens, ether, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

I've tried approving with multiple different `spender` addresses but no luck.

Token approval works fine when I try a different token, e.g. `DAI`. I've made sure I have the correct `KNC` contract address and correct `spender` addresses. I'm not even able to approve the `spender` when it's something so standard as the `Uniswap V2 Router` contract.

I've also checked to ensure the `tokenQty` is less than or equal to the tokens I have in my account, and that it is being passed down as a BN.

Here are the contract addresses I'm using (all Ropsten):

```
KNC: '0x7B2810576aa1cce68F2B118CeF1F36467c648F92'
KYBER_NETWORK_PROXY_ADDRESS: '0xd719c34261e099Fdb33030ac8909d5788D3039C4'
KYBER_NETWORK_PROXY_ADDRESS_ALT: '0x818E6FECD516Ecc3849DAf6845e3EC868087B755'
UNISWAP_ROUTER_V2_ADDRESS: '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
```

Here is my token approval helper function:

```
const approveTokenTrade = async (
  tokenSymbol: string,
  tokenQty: number,
  addressToApprove: string,
  web3: Web3
) => {
  const accountAddress = getAccountAddress();
  const chainId = getChainId();
  const privateKey = getPrivateKey();

  const tokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
    ERC20_TOKEN_ABI,
    TOKEN_SYMBOL_TO_ADDRESS_MAP.get(tokenSymbol)
  );

  const approveTxData = tokenInstance.methods
    .approve(addressToApprove, tokenQty)
    .encodeABI();

  const approveTxObject = {
    from: accountAddress,
    to: TOKEN_SYMBOL_TO_ADDRESS_MAP.get(tokenSymbol),
    data: approveTxData,
    chainId,
    gas: 4000000,
  };

  const signedApproveTxObject = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    approveTxObject,
    privateKey
  );

  await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
    signedApproveTxObject.rawTransaction as string
  );
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the same code works for other tokens like DAI then the problem isn't your code but the contract you are calling. Did you check possible error conditions on the token contract?

Comment: Yes, you are spot on. Please see my response below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `KNC` has a further condition in it's `approve` method. I had overlooked it assuming it'll have the standard `ERC20` approve method but it does not. The further condition can be seen in:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {

    // To change the approve amount you first have to reduce the addresses`
    //  allowance to zero by calling `approve(_spender, 0)` if it is not
    //  already 0 to mitigate the race condition described here:
    //  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    require((_value == 0) || (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0));

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }
```

Where now we have `require((_value == 0) || (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0))`.

This means you have to "reset" the approved value to zero if you've approved it previously for the same `spender`. Then you can approve the new amount.

**So the approval now works fine (I can see the successful transactions).**

But now I have a new problem.

The downstream trade on any of the exchange contracts (e.g. `Kyber Network Proxy`) fails with error: `SafeERC20: low-level call failed`. Similarly, I get the error `'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'` on `Uniswap Router V2`, which is usually due to lack of approval too.

This doesn't make sense to me as I've already successfully approved a very large amount equal to 2^255 for those `spenders`. I'm also sending it from the same `to` address, so `msg.sender` is the same for the approval and the trade attempt.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question.